# Parse thru json onchange after onload without getting JSON again using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently running a getJSON function on load that goes something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //get year
   var curr_year = $("#year").val(); //returns 2014 from select menu

   $.getJSON(URL, function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
               if(item.year == curr_year){
               //do stuffstuff
               }
            })  
     });

   $("#year").change(function(){
     curr_year = $("#year").val();
     $.each(json, function(i, item) {
               if(item.year == curr_year){
               //do stuffstuff
               }
            })  
   });

});//end on ready
```

Currently the onchange won't work because I do not know how to utilize the already called json in on change. Could someone show me how to accomplish this without having to call the json again?

Thank you

Comment: Create another variable and store the `$.getJSON` output into it to be used later.

Comment: This is probably answered several times already on stack, you should search a bit more before posting, one quick answer would be to write your JSON to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the result in a variable that both functions have access to (global)

```
var myJson;
$.getJSON(URL, function(json) {
    myJson = json;
    $.each(json, function(i, item) {
           if(item.year == curr_year){
           //do stuffstuff
           }
        })  
 });
```

`myJson` now has your response. However! That `get` call is async, so your change could execute before your data has came back, resulting in a null exception. Be sure to add a check!

Comment: how would I go about adding that check? Also Thank you very very much! :D

Comment: @BaconJuice -- Just do a check for `myJson` - `if (myJson) //do stuff`

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the JSON in some var after you have made the call for it, something like below (will require some clean up). Once you have your JSON you can then assign the change observer which will at this point have the JSON available.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //get year
   var curr_year = $("#year").val(); //returns 2014 from select menu

   $.getJSON(URL, function(json) {

        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
           if(item.year == curr_year){
           //do stuffstuff
           }
        });
        // now you can assign your onchange event
        $("#year").change(function(){
          curr_year = $("#year").val();
          $.each(json, function(i, item) {
           if(item.year == curr_year){
           //do stuffstuff
           }
          })  
        });
    });
});//end on ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Or nest the onchange in the getJSON callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   //get year
   var curr_year = $("#year").val(); //returns 2014 from select menu

   $.getJSON(URL, function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
               if(item.year == curr_year){
               //do stuffstuff
               }
            }); 

         $("#year").change(function(){
             $.each(json, function(i, item) {
                 if(item.year == curr_year){
                 //do stuffstuff
                 }
              })  
         });

     });


});//end on ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare the json variable in a scope that both function can access. In this case I would declare it right after curr_year like so:

```
var curr_year = $("#year").val(); //returns 2014 from select menu
var json = {};
```

Now the json data loaded with getJSON should be available to you in the change event handler function.